# Entity Framework - set navigation property null but still can't save entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**UPDATED**: Now using InverseProperty but error has not changed. I followed this tutorial:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Using Code First and *not* using lazy loading. I'm trying to save the following entity:

```
public class BlackList {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BlackListID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string OffenderUserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SellerUserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime OffenseDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OffenderUserID")]
    public ApplicationUser OffenderUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SellerUserID")]
    public ApplicationUser SellerUser { get; set; }
    public BlackList() {
        OffenderUser = new ApplicationUser();
        SellerUser = new ApplicationUser();
    }
}
```

...which is related to ApplicationUser (Identity Framework):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    [InverseProperty("OffenderUser")]
    public List<BlackList> OffenderBlackLists { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("SellerUser")]
    public List<BlackList> SellerBlackLists { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser() {
        OffenderBlackLists = new List<BlackList>();
        SellerBlackLists = new List<BlackList>();
    }
}
```

...like so:

```
            var blacklist = new BlackList {
                OffenderUserID = offenderUserID,
                SellerUserID = sellerUserID,
                OffenseDate = DateTime.Now,
                OffenderUser = null,
                SellerUser = null
            };
            db.Blacklists.Add(blacklist);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

...and am still getting this error:

> The UserName field is required.

UserName is in IdentityUser - it wasn't generated in BlackList - that table looks exactly like its POCO entity above.

This seems to suggest that setting the two *User navigation properties to null is being ignored, and attempting to insert one for each.

Comment: check fields of  table "BlackList"  in database.

Comment: @Iraj - It's code first, so this entity is the table. What you see is what you get, and everything seems to be properly defined. It's complaining about UserName, which is in ApplicationUser.

Comment: yes , it's code first ,but BlackList table and its relation with "ApplicationUser" was generated from your poco classes ,and i guess BlackList table was generated with extra fields for relation with ApplicationUser table.if its true ,then you should correct navigation of poco classes ,if you need more help complete question with your ApplicationUser class;

Comment: @Iraj - Thought InverseProperty would fix this - hadn't realized it was necessary when using two FKs to one table. Despite being valid and requiring no changes to the tables, the error is the same. Posted updates. Thanks.

Comment: @Iraj - Apologies. This error is entirely unrelated to the code I've posted. I goofed this post so bad, I'm just going to start a new one. Thanks, anyhow.